# CSS column structure within <dl>

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm working on a particular project where I do not have control over the markup, which is generated similar to below (simplified). However, the client would like a bootstrap-like column structure applied to a `<dl>` where the `<dt>` & `<dd>` pairs are treated as grouped together in a column and everything wraps appropriately based on width. There will also be responsive classes so I can't simply absolute position everything or some other non-dynamic solution. I've tried grid, flex, floats, etc. and I'm starting to think that a CSS only solution is not possible. Is something like this possible without changing HTML?

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#wrapper{
  padding: 15px;
}
.row{
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: -15px;
    margin-right: -15px;
}
dt, dd {
    float: left;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}
dt + dd {
    clear: left;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
input{
    width: 100%;
}
.col-1 {
    width: 33.3333333333%;
}
.col-2 {
    width: 66.6666666667%;
}
.col-3 {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
 <div id="wrapper">
   <dl class="row">
    <dt class="col-1">Example Text 1</dt>
    <dd class="col-1">
      <input type="text">
    </dd>
    <dt class="col-2">Example Text 2</dt>
    <dd class="col-2">
      <input type="text">
    </dd>
    <dt class="col-3">Example Text 3</dt>
    <dd class="col-3">
      <input type="text">
    </dd>
    <dt class="col-1">Example Text 4</dt>
    <dd class="col-1">
      <input type="text">
    </dd>
    <dt class="col-2">Example Text 5</dt>
    <dd class="col-2">
      <input type="text">
    </dd>
  </dl>
 <div>
```

---

To clarify, something like this would be the ideal expected output. But as I mentioned I cannot change the markup, only the CSS.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#wrapper {
  padding: 15px;
}

.row {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-right: -15px;
}

[class^="col-"] {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  margin-bottom:15px;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
}

.col-1 {
  width: 33.3333333333%;
}

.col-2 {
  width: 66.6666666667%;
}

.col-3 {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-1">
      <label>Example Text 1</label>
      <input type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
      <label>Example Text 2</label>
      <input type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
      <label>Example Text 3</label>
      <input type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="col-1">
      <label>Example Text 4</label>
      <input type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
      <label>Example Text 5</label>
      <input type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
```

Comment: maybe it's me, but what is the expected output for the above code? can you share a image of the expected output?

Comment: I've edited the question with another example of how it should look but with different markup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easy using CSS Grid layout - you can use a 3-column layout and and each of the `col-n` elements can occupy n columns using `grid-column: n`. Now fill in the holes in the layout using `grid-auto-flow: dense` - see demo below:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#wrapper {
  padding: 15px;
}

.row {
  display: grid; /* grid container */
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr); /* 3 equal columns */
  grid-gap: 10px; /* row and column gap */
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
}

.col-1 {
  grid-column: 1; /* first column */
}

.col-2 {
  grid-column: span 2; /* occuppy 2 columns */
}

.col-3 {
  grid-column: span 3; /* occupy 3 columns */
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <dl class="row">
    <dt class="col-1">Example Text 1</dt>
    <dd class="col-1">
      <input type="text">
    </dd>
    <dt class="col-2">Example Text 2</dt>
    <dd class="col-2">
      <input type="text">
    </dd>
    <dt class="col-3">Example Text 3</dt>
    <dd class="col-3">
      <input type="text">
    </dd>
    <dt class="col-1">Example Text 4</dt>
    <dd class="col-1">
      <input type="text">
    </dd>
    <dt class="col-2">Example Text 5</dt>
    <dd class="col-2">
      <input type="text">
    </dd>
  </dl>
  <div>
```

Comment: This is actually exactly what I need. For some reason I couldn't get grid to work. Do you happen to know the browser support limitations? I need to support IE11+ unfortunately

Comment: @AlexM may not work well in IE11 though but okay in Edge, see https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid

Comment: Thanks! We may just have to have an IE fallback but I'm accepting your answer

Comment: @AlexM the grid could also be set : `.row {
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:1fr 2fr;
  grid-auto-flow:dense;
}
.col-1 {
  grid-column:1;
}
.col-2 {
  grid-column:2;
}
.col-3 {
  grid-column:1 / span 2;
}`  for the same layout result. here is a couple of usefull links : https://gridbyexample.com/ and https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/ have fun with the grid system ;)

Comment: @AlexM for IE there was a polyfill : demo to check if that works for you (it works for My IE11 )https://rawgit.com/FremyCompany/css-grid-polyfill/master/demo/css-grid/layout4.html  From : https://github.com/FremyCompany/css-grid-polyfill/

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're going for? I'm not sure I understand when you say "everything wraps appropriately based on width".

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#wrapper {
  padding: 15px;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row: flex-wrap:wrap;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-right: -15px;
}

.dl-group {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

dt,
dd {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

dt+dd {
  clear: left;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
}

.col-1 {
  width: 33.3333333333%;
}

.col-2 {
  width: 66.6666666667%;
}

.col-3 {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <dl class="row">
    <div class="dl-group">
      <dt class="col-1">Example Text 1</dt>
      <dd class="col-1">
        <input type="text">
      </dd>
    </div>

    <div class="dl-group">
      <dt class="col-2">Example Text 2</dt>
      <dd class="col-2">
        <input type="text">
      </dd>
    </div>

    <div class="dl-group">
      <dt class="col-3">Example Text 3</dt>
      <dd class="col-3">
        <input type="text">
      </dd>
    </div>

    <div class="dl-group">
      <dt class="col-1">Example Text 4</dt>
      <dd class="col-1">
        <input type="text">
      </dd>
    </div>

    <div class="dl-group">
      <dt class="col-2">Example Text 5</dt>
      <dd class="col-2">
        <input type="text">
      </dd>
    </div>
  </dl>
  <div>
```

Comment: Not quite, but close. I've added an edit to the question for clarification